# Как обратиться к ui в своей функции?

Tags: c++, qt

Нужно сделать функцию для вывода вектора в `plainTextEdit`. Если пытаюсь установить текст этому элементу, например, при клике на кнопку, то использую это:

```
ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str);
```

Но при попытке сделать тоже самое в своей функции я не могу обратиться к `ui->`, чтобы потом установить текст в `plainTextEdit`. Просто появляется ошибка "Use of undeclared identifier 'ui'".
Вот сама функция:

```
void print_vector(std::vector<Student>& vc)
{
    std::vector<Student>::iterator it_s = vc.begin();
    QString str;

    for (int id = 0; it_s != vc.end(); it_s++, id++)
    {

        QString qs_id = QString::number(id);
        str += qs_id + " Имя: " + vc[id].name + "\t Возраст: " + vc[id].age + "\tБаллы: " + vc[id].score + "\n";
    }
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str); //вот здесь ошибка
}
```

Comment: Приведите код. Пока не очень понятно, что Вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Стало понятнее. Здесь Вы никак не сможете добраться до ui, тем более, что неизвестно, до какого ui надо добраться (их, в принципе, может быть сколько угодно, по одному для каждого существующего в программе окна, а может и не только :))  ) . Вам нужно в классе окна сделать открытую функцию, выполняющую установку текста на элемент, а в своей функции обращаться к этой функции. Но не забывайте: Ваша функция должна иметь доступ к объекту окна.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Просто верните полученную строку, то есть вместо `ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str);` надо `return str;`, а там где вам нужна эта строка (в объекте окна, в котором есть ui) `ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(print_vector(...));`

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь вы основы ООП игнорируете не из религиозных и прочих побуждений? :)
Ваша функция находится вне класса, и потому взаимодействовать с ним не может.
Включите вашу функцию в класс и не придется изобретать велосипед (не забудьте в .h добавить)

```
void MainWindow::print_vector(std::vector<Student>& vc)
{
    std::vector<Student>::iterator it_s = vc.begin();
    QString str;

    for (int id = 0; it_s != vc.end(); it_s++, id++)
    {

        QString qs_id = QString::number(id);
        str += qs_id + " Имя: " + vc[id].name + "\t Возраст: " + vc[id].age + "\tБаллы: " + vc[id].score + "\n";
    }
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str); //вот здесь ошибка
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй наоборот)) если нет доступа к класу окна и не можеш использовать его функционал то сделай функционал своего класа так что б ты мог его использовать в методах оконного класа))

```
QString print_vector(std::vector<Student>& vc)
{
std::vector<Student>::iterator it_s = vc.begin();
QString str;

for (int id = 0; it_s != vc.end(); it_s++, id++)
{

    QString qs_id = QString::number(id);
    str += qs_id + " Имя: " + vc[id].name + "\t Возраст: " + vc[id].age + "\tБаллы: " + vc[id].score + "\n";
}
 
return str;
}


void MainWindow::on_PrintButton_clicked()
{
 std::vector<Student>& vc;
 void fillGivenVector(vc); 
 QString str = print_vector(vc);  //youre function (name should be changed)
 
 ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(str); //c этого метода есть доступ 

}
```